# Rolling windows excluding current rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Here is a dataframe example:

```
days = ['2019-07-04 17:02:03', '2019-07-04 17:03:03',
        '2019-07-04 18:04:03', '2019-07-04 19:05:03',
        '2019-07-04 21:06:03', '2019-07-04 21:36:03',
        '2019-07-04 21:50:03', '2019-07-04 22:10:03']
ddf = pd.DataFrame({'Val': [0, 1, 2, 1, 4,1,3,1],'Cat':["A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"]},
                  index= days)
ddf.index = pd.to_datetime(ddf.index)

                     Val Cat
2019-07-04 17:02:03    0   A
2019-07-04 17:03:03    1   A
2019-07-04 18:04:03    2   A
2019-07-04 19:05:03    1   A
2019-07-04 21:06:03    4   B
2019-07-04 21:36:03    1   B
2019-07-04 21:50:03    3   B
2019-07-04 22:10:03    1   B
```

If I apply rolling sum with 1 hour windows I get this:

```
ddf.groupby("Cat")["Val"].rolling("1h").sum().rename('sum_last_hour')

Cat                     
A    2019-07-04 17:02:03    0.0
     2019-07-04 17:03:03    1.0
     2019-07-04 18:04:03    2.0
     2019-07-04 19:05:03    1.0
B    2019-07-04 21:06:03    4.0
     2019-07-04 21:36:03    5.0
     2019-07-04 21:50:03    8.0
     2019-07-04 22:10:03    5.0
Name: sum_last_hour, dtype: float64
Name: sum_last_hour, dtype: float64
```

But I want to obtain this:

```
Cat                     
A    2019-07-04 17:02:03    NaN
     2019-07-04 17:03:03    0.0
     2019-07-04 18:04:03    NaN
     2019-07-04 19:05:03    NaN
B    2019-07-04 21:06:03    NaN
     2019-07-04 21:36:03    4.0
     2019-07-04 21:50:03    5.0
     2019-07-04 22:10:03    4.0
Name: sum_last_hour, dtype: float64
```

So I basically want to exclude the current row from the rolling sum if that makes sense...
I tried using shift() but without success for now. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why are the values null in the first group after 0?

Comment: Because there wasn't any new value in the last hour

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually I just found out about it. You need to use the `closed` parameter in the `rolling()` function and set it to `left`. Something like this gives me the good result:

```
ddf.groupby("Cat").rolling("1h", closed= "left")["Val"].sum().rename('sum_last_hour')
```

Comment: I was struggling with this for a few hours... tried all sorts of things... I'd been using closed='right' or 'both' but never thought to use ' left'....

Comment: This was a godsend suggestion. Works perfectly.