# Python: rolling hour time count of categorical variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with columns `['DateTime', 'Variable']`, and I'm trying to get a rolling count in the ***last hour*** for each `Variable`. Thinking pivot could be used somehow.

Sample data

```
DateTime             Variable
8/24/19 3:30PM       A
8/24/19 3:32PM       A
8/24/19 3:36PM       B
8/24/19 3:50PM       C
8/25/19 2:50PM       A
```

Expected output

```
DateTime          A    B    C
8/24/19 3:30PM    1    0    0 
8/24/19 3:32PM    2    0    0  
8/24/19 3:36PM    2    1    0 
8/24/19 3:50PM    2    1    1
8/25/19 2:50PM    1    0    0
```

New variables may be added or removed so I'd like to have a solution that is dynamic.

Comment: @RichieV I essentially want to count the number of times each Variable appeared in the last hour based on my time stamp. At 8/24/19 3:32, there is one A and a second A (within the last hour) at 3:30 so at that point in time there have been 2 A's in the last hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could in fact start with `pivot`, or doing it *by hand* with `groupby.unstack`.

Then you are looking for `df.rolling` to create [rolling windows](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/computation.html#window-functions) that can be aggregated with many functions. In order for the windows to be created with a timedelta (1 hour in this case) you need to make sure the index is of `datetime` type.

```py
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])

out = (
    df
    .groupby(['DateTime', 'Variable']) # set the columns as index
    .size() # aggregate by row count
    .unstack(fill_value=0) # move 'Variable' index level to columns
    .sort_index()
)

out = out.rolling('1h').sum()
```

Output

```
Variable               A    B    C
DateTime
2019-08-24 15:30:00  1.0  0.0  0.0
2019-08-24 15:32:00  2.0  0.0  0.0
2019-08-24 15:36:00  2.0  1.0  0.0
2019-08-24 15:50:00  2.0  1.0  1.0
2019-08-25 14:50:00  1.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: This is a very nice simple solution! I will also want to avoid counting the current row when doing the rolling calculation, but I can use shift for that.

Comment: see [rolling windows excluding current row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56886614/6692898)

Answer (score 0):

Considering df is your dataset:
new_df = df[df['Variable']== 'A'].resample('H').count()

You can create a new dataframe as follows:
final_df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime':new_df.index, 'A': new_df.values})

Similarly, take the count for each category of the Variable column and try to concat it to the final_df using loop.

I haven't tried it but hopefully it would work.

Comment: This code would only count each row once and group them by hour... what OP asked for is a rolling count, where any row could be counted several times if it fell into several windows...also, read [how do I format my code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/6692898)

Comment: Thank you. This was close, but by using df['Variable']== 'A', it's not able to count the B's in the last hour for that particular time stamp that only had 'A'. However, I was able to get close using a cross tab, a loop, and your method!