# Get index of the data slices in df.groupby().rolling()

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm tring to do rolling apply using multiple columns. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60918101/2771265) in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736556/pandas-rolling-apply-using-multiple-columns) is slow because it needs to slice the original data for every window. I can't use numba or numpy_ext so the other answers don't apply.

I notice that list(df.groupby().rolling()) actually gives me all the data slices I need but it doesn't have the window index so I don't know which window this data slice belongs to. If I can have the indexes, I think
`pd.concat(df.groupby(g).rolling(on=r), keys=<indexes I'm looking for>).groupby([g, r]).apply(my_func)` will give me the result I need. Basically I'm looking for something like the keys in df.groupby().groups.

It's *almost* possible to construct the index manually. The index has two parts, the group from the groupby and the slice from the rolling. For the former, I can duplicate the groupby columns to retain the info. For the latter, it's usually in the data slice but its position depends on the type of the rolling window. If the window closes at right, then it's the last row in the data slice, if the window is centered, it's the middle row but a bit tricky to decide exactly if the window size is even. However, it's [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56886004/rolling-windows-excluding-current-rows) to have a window that doesn't include the "current row" then I'm stuck.

Is there a clean way to get the index, or at least the slice index from the rolling, or a fast way to do rolling apply using multiple columns?

Comment: [i.index.values for i in df.groupby('name_columns').rolling(3) if len(i) == 3]   ?